Control-C and Control-V do not work in Memo in FireMonkey
I have a Delphi multi-platform application. I would like to allow my users to copy and paste text in a TMemo component. I have 2 buttons for copy and paste. It works fine, but using Control-C and Control-V in a Windows application is a good thing. My users don't want to use a paste button. They want to use Control-V.
This event is not working in FireMonkey. Why?
procedure TFrameMemoLineCount.mTxtKeyDown(Sender: TObject; var Key: Word;
var KeyChar: WideChar; Shift: TShiftState);  
begin

  if (Key = vkC) and (ssCtrl in Shift) then
  begin
    mTxt.CopyToClipboard;
    Key := 0; // Prevenir o processamento adicional da tecla
  end;
  if (Key = vkV) and (ssCtrl in Shift) then
  begin
    mTxt.PasteFromClipboard;
    Key := 0; // Prevenir o processamento adicional da tecla
  end;

end;


Doesn't the FMX TMemo control give you Ctrl+ZXCV support out of the box?

unfortunately not, but if you use right button mouse show paste menu and user can use this.

I just tried to create a new FMX app in Delphi 11.3, with a single TMemo control, and on my Windows 11 computer, Ctrl+ZXCV works in this app.

have you used keydown event ? Im using delphi 12.1 Athens

No. I created a new FMX application. I dropped a TMemo on the main form (and made it larger) and then I ran the application by pressing F9. Then I was able to Ctrl+X, C, V in the memo.

Thank you very much for your help. I will try discover why it not works for me. its much strang it not work for me. Do you think my code posted is correct ?

Is your event handler being called?  As Andreas said, Ctrl-C,V work out of the box, and your sample code also works for me.

@LeonardoPereira do you have the TMemo.ControlStyle property set to Styled (default) or Platform (native)?

I Change ControlType Property in TMemo to Plataform value and now it works. Thanks !!! @RemyLebeau

I would like thanks to @AndreasRejbrand

i would like thanks to @RemyLebeau for this tip

i would like thanks @PhilipJ.Rayment for coments too. Thanks all of you

Set the Memo's ControlStyle property to Platform to enable native OS control behaviors. It is set to Styled by default.
See Embarcadero documentation for more details:
FireMonkey Native Controls
